# cannot access TypeStoreUser Error while building XMLBeans 2.6.0 using ANT

Tags: java, ant, apache-poi, xmlbeans

I am trying to build XMLBeans source code downloaded from git using ant. But I am getting this error -

```
 xmlbeans\src\xmlcomp\org\apache\xmlbeans\impl\tool\SchemaCompiler.java:221: 
 error: cannot access TypeStoreUser

[javac]                 
          new HashSet(Arrays.asList(XmlListImpl.split_list(allowmdef))));
[javac]                                                      ^
[javac]   class file for org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.TypeStoreUser not found
```

Please provide solutions to resolve this issue. XMLBeans version is 2.6.0

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: Which Git repo did you download from? IIRC Apache XMLBeans canonical source is SVN

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error, when I was trying to build with Java 1.8. It was building for me with java 1.7.

For java 1.8 I made this change in the `build.xml` file and it worked. Under `target name="xmlcomp.classes"`, add 'typestore' in classpath, like:

```
<pathelement location="build/classes/typestore"/>
```